# Store several accounts in the AccountManager and include a SyncAdapter

Tags: android, authentication, android-preferences, android-syncadapter, accountmanager

I'm facing the following scenario. My app uses the AccountManager to store the users credentials. It is possible to be logged in more than one account at the same time, similar to what twitter does (you can go to your profile and switch to a different logged account). One one of the logged accounts is considered active at a time.

Until know, the way I used to identify which account is currently being used by the user is to store the current account name in the SharedPreferences. In this way, you can just retrieve this name from prefs at any time, get the list of logged accounts in the account manager and iterate until you get the proper Account object. Something like this:

```
String currentAccountName = SharedPreferences.get(mContext).getString(PREF_CURRENT_ACCOUNT, null);
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(mContext).getAccountsByType(MY_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
Account loggedAccount;
for (Account account : accounts) {
    if (account.name.equals(currentAccountName)) {
          loggedAccount = account;
          break;
    }
}

//Get the token for this account
String authToken = AccountManager.get(mContext).getToken(account, MY_ACCOUNT_TYPE,...).getResult().get(AccountManager.AUTH_TOKEN);
```

Also, when running the SyncAdapter, its gets the currentAccountName from preferences to get a token and connect to the server.

The problem is that, from API 21 it is no longer safe to access the preferences from different processes. This mean that, if I store into prefs the currentLoggedAccount and then I launch a Sync Adapter, it might not get the stored pref, because its executed in a different process.

How would you handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this same problem. I made a workaround using my local DB. As i use `Realm` in my app, i made a table which acts as `SharedPreference`, i store them like a key value pair. And then retrieved the value because as you said from API 21 it is no longer dependable to access the preferences from different processes.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Abir. This will work but still feels like an overkill to me. Creating an SQL table just to store one single row of information make me think that there must be something else that I'm missing.